# CrossDomain Cookie Sharing

Tags: asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on

I am having three different ASP.Net web-apps in three different domains like as following,
1. App1.Domain1.com
2. App1.Domain2.com
3. App1.Domain3.com

I want to develop SSO based authentication and authorization. All my users are in Active Directory. 
All are having different url as I mentioned above. I strongly believe that we need to share the cookies from one app to another for SSO based development.
Please advice me whether I am following correct way. If it is not correct please suggest me the correct way of development.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you use ADFS? That would be a more conventional solution

Comment: Yes. That is also our thought to proceed further. But, with the help of ADFS can we share cookie throughout the cross domain? If so plz suggest me how can we?              Plz help me!

Comment: That's not how ADFS works. It would make this cookie sharing unnecessary for the purpose of authentication. I suggest you do some research about how modern SSO solutions (such as ADFS and other identity providers) actually work. It is all based on access tokens and claims. Sharing cookies should not be the goal of your work.

Comment: Using Azure AD might be another viable solution. Or IdentityServer and Oauth. There are a few possibilities